Entity Framework Core model annotation
I want to implement migrations for row level security policies in my project. The idea is to mark the model with an annotation, then intercept the generation of the migration and generate some SQL for the row level security.
In my DbContext.OnModelCreating I have the following code:
modelBuilder.Entity<Widget>()
    .HasAnnotation("TenantIsolationPolicy", new RlsPolicy(...));

RlsPolicy is a class that contains data that are needed to generate the SQL (name of policy, who it applies to, type of policy, ...)
Then I have a custom ModelDiffer which handles the "business logic" of reading the annotation data and generating SQL based on it. I am able to build the code, but I get an error when I try to add a migration: Cannot scaffold C# literals of type 'XYZ.RlsPolicy'. The provider should implement CoreTypeMapping.GenerateCodeLiteral to support using it at design time.
Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.indexbuilder-1.hasannotation?view=efcore-5.0 I was expecting to be able to pass a class as the second parameter and then in the differ I'm using code like this to safely access the data:
var sourceTableAnnotation = entityType.GetAnnotations()?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "TenantIsolationPolicy");

if (sourceTableAnnotation != null &&
    sourceTableAnnotation.Value is RlsPolicy sourcePayload) 
{
    ...
}

I'm using EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.9 and Npgsql 5.0.7
Is my assumption about passing data from the OnConfiguring method to the custom model differ incorrect ?

Pass annotastion as string, otherwise you should provide serilizer as mentioned in error message.
